# Adjust Width from the Left Side of Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Changing the width of a container defaults to resizing from the right side.
The pseudocode below has an example where dx is a variable that can change. When it increases or decreases, the container will always grow or shrink from the right side.
Is there a simple way to switch the direction so that the width will increase or decrease from the left side instead of the right side?

```dart
    Container( 
               width: dx,
               height:200
   )
```

Here is a dartpad gist that shows how the right side of the container's width changes when dragged. What I'm asking is if there is a quick and simple way to make the left side expand/contract without having to animate the position of the container: https://dartpad.dev/?id=ebbe57041bf950018fe5733674c68b20

Comment: can you include full sample widget from scaffold body. In flutter patter position the child.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I've added a dartpad gist to better get the idea. You can drag the right side, but the left side logic needs to work the same. I'm wondering if there is a general way to do this, which is just as straight forward as how the right side expansion/contraction works by changing the width.

Comment: I think you can play with `alingment` property

Comment: Not sure how this could work since my understanding of alignment is that it is related to how the children are aligned within the container. Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out your dartpad code. To achieve what you want, I suggest you put two empty `Containers` on either side of your handles and decrease their size when the handles are dragged (your center `Container` should also be inside an `Expanded` widget to take up all the allowed space). here is the example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Application name
      title: 'Flutter Stateful Clicker Counter',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // Application theme data, you can set the colors for the application as
        // you want
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Clicker Counter Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double? rightContainerWidth, leftContainerWidth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    rightContainerWidth ??= MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 20;
    leftContainerWidth ??= MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 20;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              // left handle
              Container(
                width: leftContainerWidth,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                    setState(() {
                      leftContainerWidth = details.globalPosition.dx;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          )),
                      width: 10,
                      height: 200)),

              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    //  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),

                    child: ClipRect(
                        child: Container(
                  //   width: _counter+0.2,
                  height: 200,

                  color: Colors.green,
                ))),
              ),

              GestureDetector(
                  onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
                    print("st: ${details.localPosition.dx}");
                    // dx for start is the x offset of the mouse relative to the container
                    //   changeX = (_counter as double) - details.localPosition.dx.floor();
                  },
                  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                    setState(() {
                      // print(details.localPosition.dx);
                      rightContainerWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
                          details.globalPosition.dx;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      width: 10,
                      height: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                          )))),
              Container(
                width: rightContainerWidth,
              ),
            ])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Caution: I did not add conditional statements to prevent overflows, make sure you also add them!

Comment: I see what you mean here. The `mainAxisAlignment.end` will cause the container to shift to the other side and grow from the opposite side, but the visible shift to the end is undesirable.  One would have to switch between `mainAxisAlignment.end` and `mainAxisAlignment.start` without having a visible change in the alignment.

Comment: then I don't understand what you mean by growing from the left side. If your widgets are on the left side of the screen  and you want them to grow from left, then that would cause an overflow.

Comment: In the dartpad you saw a container being expanded from the right when you drag the right handle. What's needed is that the container should expand from the left when the left handle is dragged.  It shouldn't matter whether the container is aligned at the start or end of the main axis. One way to make this work from the left is to change the position of the container while changing the width in opposition. I was hoping there would be some even simpler way to do it in flutter.

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you mean now. I edited my answer. hope it helps

Comment: This solution involves extra containers. I was hoping that there was some even simpler thing in flutter that would allow it, but it looks like the two options are moving the container while adjusting the width or using an expanded container and adjusting two extra containers.  I will select this as the answer.

Comment: @Kdigital i think you are more used to how android native development works. In flutter we dont have such a thing. Widgets are placed based on their size and aligntment of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Wrap` Widget

A widget that displays its children in multiple horizontal or vertical runs.

A Wrap lays out each child and attempts to place the child adjacent to the previous child in the main axis, given by direction, leaving spacing space in between. If there is not enough space to fit the child, Wrap creates a new run adjacent to the existing children in the cross axis.

After all the children have been allocated to runs, the children within the runs are positioned according to the alignment in the main axis and according to the crossAxisAlignment in the cross axis.

The runs themselves are then positioned in the cross axis according to the runSpacing and runAlignment.

Example:

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: <Widget>[
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('AH')),
      label: const Text('Hamilton'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('ML')),
      label: const Text('Lafayette'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('HM')),
      label: const Text('Mulligan'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('JL')),
      label: const Text('Laurens'),
    ),
  ],
)
```